# How to remove parent theme image sizes in Magento 2.1

Tags: image, magento-2.1

A purchased theme contains many different image sizes, most of which we will not use.

To speed up image processing, is there a way to remove these definitions from within the child theme without removing the original definitions in the parent theme's view.xml file?

e.g. in the same way a block can be removed, could an image definition be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the theme `view.xml` file contents overwrites that of the parent - if it is not mentioned in there, it isn't generated.